# Does elasticsearch CCR feature replicates ILM?

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, elastic-stack, ccr, ilm

It might that it is not correct question, but I have created ILM on my leader cluster, however I don't see that it is replicated to follower cluster.

Am I right in thinking that it should not be replicated at all because it is not related to index entity, however I haven't seen that documented somewhere. Let's suppose I would like to unfollow and use follower cluster as my new "leader" in case of previous leader disaster.

Does it mean that I have to create ILM on follower also from the very beginning or prior "switching"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Policies - separate entities that are not related to the indices, so if you want policies to be applied on indices - it should be pre-created.